# How to open a popup using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I would like to know how to open a popup using Ajax, instead of jQuery, so when I click in the link that will open it, an action is executed to load some collections and other stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'ajax instead of jQuery'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i think you are messing up some concepts here.
JQuery is a javascript framework and AJAX is a set of development methods.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29
and: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery

I think that you mean "How do i open a link in a lightbox like screen instead of a javascript popup".
(correct me if im wrong interpreting your question :)

Please take a look at some open source tools like:
http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/
http://fancybox.net/

And there are tons and tons of other alternatives.
Just google for "lightbox"